# borderless child NSWindow not getting events

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I create a NSWindow with this code, but I don't receive any mouse or keyboard events for it:

```
window = [[OverlayWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:bounds styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
[parentWindow addChildWindow:window ordered:NSWindowAbove];
NSView * rootView = [[OverlayView alloc] init];
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[window setContentView:rootView];
[window setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO];
[self reshapeToRect:bounds];
```

and in OverlayWindow:

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow { return YES; }
- (BOOL) canBecomeMainWindow { return YES; }
- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder { return YES; }
- (BOOL) becomeFirstResponder { return YES; }
- (BOOL) resignFirstResponder { return YES; }
```

Comment: Go ahead and post your edit as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[window orderWindow:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:[parentWindow windowNumber]];
```

did the trick